# How to add Fontawesome to an Angular app and get the icons to appear

Tags: angular, font-awesome-5

I added

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.15.1"
```

to `dependencies` in my `package.json`
and then I added to my html

```
<span class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></span>
```

but nothing shows up.

What do I need to do? It's completely unclear.

I'm in a project created by VisualStudio and it has Twitter Bootstrap in the `package.json` and that appears to be working without bootstrap being mentioned anywhere else, so why doesn't it work for FontAwesome?

This doesn't work.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    '../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Adding to `styles.css`:

```
@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.min.css";
```

also doesn't work. This is crap.

What was so bad about adding a `<link>` in the `<head>`? This is awful.

Comment: you wrote '../../node_modules/@foRRRRRRtawesome not ../node_modules/@foNNNNNNNNtawesome

Answer (score 1):

## Adding third-party global styles to angular.json

In your angular.json file you'll have a property that is meant to describe files or globs to include in your webpack build.

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "styles": [] // add the path here.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, for your case of font-awesome, it would look something like the following:

```json
"styles": [
   "src/styles.scss",
  "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
]
```

To get that file, download the corresponding fortawesome-package as described on their [website](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/packages#the-free-package) :

```bash
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Once you've modified your `angular.json` you will have to restart your angular cli for the changes to take effect.

#### Why can you not add it directly to `index.html`'s head section.

The reason for this is that the index.html you will distribute is being generated by webpack once you run `ng build` so you have to take this extra step in telling the webpack toolchain to include your style in the generated index.html's head.

#### More information

For more information on Angular workspace configuraiton you can check the reference guide here: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

Comment: Better. Now it's showing boxes where the icons should be.

Comment: Is this stuff documented anywhere?

Comment: Yes you can find more information on workspace configuration here: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

Answer (score 1):

For use with **Angular 9+**

You can also consider using the [`angular-fontawesome`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome) library

Steps

1. Install the dependancies

Using `npm`

```
$ npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

2. Add `FontAwesomeModule` to imports in **src/app/app.module.ts**:

```typescript
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. Tie the icon to the property in your component **src/app/app.component.ts**:

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  faCoffee = faCoffee;
}
```

4. Use the icon in the template **src/app/app.component.html**:

```html
<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>
```

Comment: I just want it to work like normal as if I'd added the link tags to the head, but apparently it can't. I'm absolutely not interested in this ridiculous complexity.

Comment: Worked fine for me. This answer is good if you only need to use Font Awesome icons in 1/2 components. If you're planning on using them throughout the application it would probably be better to use an Icon library. This link describes how to do so and the benefits: https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-use-font-awesome-icons-in-angular-applications/

Comment: This is definitely adding too much work, but that is solely because of the way fortawesome works. The attribute should've been a type union for strings. Requiring an import, a field assignment on top of the actual attribute assignment that you're really after is overkill.